# Programmatically access Code analysis results in Roslyn

Tags: roslyn, code-analysis

I'm building a tool that analyses C# snippets and provides some feedback on them. I use

`tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(codeSample);`

to get a SyntaxTree and then

`semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);`

to get a SemanticModel.

I can find syntactic errors in the code with `semanticModel.Compilation.GetDiagnostics();` but I know that there are also a bunch of code quality rules that Roslyn can perform as well ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/)) using the [Roslyn Analyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers).

My question is: how can I obtain those code-style issues in code programmatically, like I can get the syntactic errors?

Comment: How are you creating your compilation?

Comment: @PauloMorgado like this:
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("assemblyName")
                .AddReferences(
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(
                        typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
                .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);

Comment: I can't test at the moment, but there are `WitAnalyzers` methods. Can't you find one?

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it to work. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

Firstly you have to load the CodeAnalysis `.dll`, and get the analyzers from it:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll");
var analyzers = assembly.GetTypes()
                        .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<DiagnosticAnalyzerAttribute>() is object)
                        .Select(t => (DiagnosticAnalyzer)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
                        .ToArray();
```

Then, when generating the `Compilation`, add the analyzers with `WithAnalyzers(...)`:

```
var compilationWithAnalyzers = CSharpCompilation.Create("query")
                .AddReferences(
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
                ).AddSyntaxTrees(tree).WithAnalyzers(ImmutableArray.Create(analyzers));
```

After that you can get the CodeAnalysis results with:

```
var analyzerDiagnostics = (await compilationWithAnalyzers.GetAllDiagnosticsAsync()).ToList();
```